# DotNetZip password error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetzip

I am using *DotNetZip* to archive files inside a zip file, using a password.

The password I use has 144 random characters.

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "144 characters password";
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestSpeed;

    zip.AddEntry("file1.xml", data);

    zip.Save(file);
}
```

When I open the zip file from code behind (specifying the password), I can get the files inside.

If I open the archive using WinRar and set the password there, it tells me that the password is invalid.

What can be the reason for this issue? Can it be because the password length is too big?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with encoding? Have you tried forcing the same encoding your OS is using?

Comment: They are only numbers in the string, so i don't think it's this issue. Anyway, i've read on [WinRar](http://www.winrar-tr.com/winrar/Help/ENG/html/HELPArcEncryption.htm) that they support maximum 127 characters

Comment: Nice to know that. Out of curiosity, though, why do you need a password that big? Are you trying to challenge Douglas Adam's Deep Thought?

Comment: I store sensitive data and it's important that nobody can open the files. Also, the password is generated by a tool which i already used in inside the project

Answer (score 3):

You're out of luck. According to their [Web site](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_archiver.htm), WinRAR only supports AES-128 and not AES-256.

> WinRAR offers you the benefit of industry strength archive encryption using AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) with a key of 128 bits.

Update: Apparently, [WinRAR 5.0 beta](http://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm) supports AES-256.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that the password length is too big. They have a maximum 127 characters password. [link](http://www.winrar-tr.com/winrar/Help/ENG/html/HELPArcEncryption.htm)

Comment: @RaraituL: It certainly may be both, though the link you gave talks about a limitation of *.rar* files (and not .zip files).